# How to make Flutter authentification just over Firestore (without Firebase Auth)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have to create a manual Registration and Sign in over Firestore without using Firebase Auth.
The reason for that requrirement is once when user wants to reset his password, first of all I have to sent him a confirmation code (MD5) on his email address and when he receives the code, above new password that he should enter, he must paste that code.
I'll sent him a code on email and in the same time, that code will be also in Firestore from which later on I will compare (code is correct or not).
By the end, (if entered code is correct, his new password will overwrite previous stored password in his document). Documents are named by email address which means that email should be unique.

Here is the code that I'm using for registration:

```
void onPressedRegister(BuildContext context, String fullName, String email,
String password, String phoneNumber, dynamic formKey) {
if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
db.collection("firestoreUsers").document(email).setData({
  'fullName': fullName,
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
  'phoneNumber': phoneNumber
});
```

Now I have a problem with Sign in because I can't check is user stored in database or not. Here is what I wrote:

```
Future<bool> signInOverFirestore(String email, String password) async {
db
    .collection('firestoreUsers')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
    .getDocuments();
return true;
}
```

So is it possible to make sign in like this and also update that user later on when he enter correct code from his email, or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Firebase Auth with Firestore and security rules, it's basically impossible to have secure per-user data. What you have now is storing plaintext email addresses and passwords for everyone in the world to see.  All someone has to do is use the Firestore REST API to query the entire firestoreUsers collection to see everything.

Comment: I got it, but that's the requirement from me to do. But I'm stuck on this. Even it's just a plaintext, I have to make it as a real credentials..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "real credentials", but there is nothing at all secure about what you're doing.

Comment: By "real credentials" I mean that fields must be used for sign in, without talking about the security. Absolutely understandable your explanation about the security facts, but for now, security is in another plan. Main point is to establish Sign In and Sign Up just through Firestore.

Comment: You can write whatever you want to the document and make use of it however you want. If you have a specific problem using the apis, please edit the question to illustrate what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to make Firestore data public (access/read without authentication) check if some document with a value and if that value doesn't exist, you want to create a new document. In order to do that you can try to fetch the document which is equal to your value(email) and catch the error or listen if it is successful. You may accomplish it with the following example.

```
_db
    .collection('path')
    .where('field', isEqualTo: '')
    .getDocuments()
    .then((value) {
  print('User on Firestore : $value');
}).catchError((e) {
  print('Error no document found');
});
```

Comment: Well you are close to the answer. I also got the instance of QuerySnapshot (like the value of your solution is), but the problem is that I don't know how to check the credentials from Firestore with user input on that screen. Normally, using firebase, I was doing like this:  await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password); but auth is instance of Firebase. 

Here I don't know how to do it just with Firestore -> without FirebaseAuth.

Comment: You'll probably have to just create new document with the user credentials to Firestore directly as a string(or other data types) if it doesn't already exist and do nothing(or update ) the firestore document if it exists.